# Fantasy trilogy from the 90s where guy starts out as the only person dragons are afraid of, and by the third book he turns into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I'm pretty sure it was under one of those banners like D&D or similar. And I remember an early scene in the first book where the guy has to ride a horse and gets incredibly saddlesore to the amusement of his fellow travelers.

Oh, I remembered another thing. The author's last name had an interesting Icelandic ending like Olafsdottir.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based off of your comment that they had an Icelandic-sounding name, I looked at the [list of D&D book authors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(novels)), and picked [Thorarinn Gunnarsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorarinn_Gunnarsson), and started searching on the titles. I'm pretty sure you're looking for the *Dragonlord Chronicles*.

*[Dragonlord of Mystara](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/612826.Dragonlord_of_Mystara)*

> As dragons roam the lands that will become Glantri, leaving havoc, destruction, and death in their wake, an unpromising young man, a female sword-fighter, her dwarven sidekick, and a ne'er-do-well storyteller and prophet set out to defend their world.

*[Dragonking of Mystara](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/440199.Dragonking_of_Mystara)*

> Establishing a shaky peace with the dragons, Dragonlord Thelvyn Fox Eyes is distraught when they attempt to use him as a pawn and weapon against their enemies in a new plot for power, which he fears will spark another war.

*[Dragonmage of Mystara](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/462812.Dragonmage_of_Mystara)*

> In the third episode, Thelvyn is a full-fledged dragon who has learned everything necessary to perform his main task. First he must find the stolen Dragon Necklace. In doing so, he finds an enemy that threatens his entire world. When he regains the Dragon Kings power badge, he becomes the Dragon King and begins to organize the defense of the country. It is high time, since the enemy has already launched an attack.

[image: Book cover of *Dragonlord of Mystara*] [image: Book cover of *Dragonking of Mystara*] [image: Book cover for *Dragonmage of Mystara*]

Incidentally, [by his own confession](https://web.archive.org/web/20040606073739/http://www.thuntek.net/hardmag/thorinn.htm), Thorarinn's claim of being Norwegian was entirely false, a backstory he created in early days of the Internet when people could be whoever they wanted to be, and which he furthered because it sold well.

Comment: I have the books, and there is indeed a scene in the first book where the main protagonist Thelvyn has to ride a horse for the first time and finds it a painful experience.

Comment: Nice work! This is like the best thing ever.

Comment: Glad I could help.